# There's a way to not re-render a component when user backs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using hashHistory to router my components, the problem is that when user went back from component to the previous one, this previous component gets reloaded. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Once the user navigates away from a component it is unloaded. So to display the component again it has to be reloaded. Is there some other problem you are trying to solve here, such as retaining its state?

Comment: It's because i'm working with a request that takes a good time (about 7s) and it would be great if it not reload.

Comment: Are you talking about reloading the component? Or reloading the data for the component? You can hold on to the data and redisplay it without getting it again.

Comment: It's because when I reload the component, I do the request. 
If I had to hold the data, it would be in the local storage?

Comment: It does not have to be in local storage. If you create a service, it can hold the data separate from any loaded component. A service is a singleton and loaded once. Any data assigned to a property of the service is available throughout the life of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought it would be possible to not reload. Thanks